# C# Linking point on form

Tags: c#, forms, bitmap, picturebox

Greeting!
I've been working on a project where you got a form where the user asks for a certain amount of dot (between 1 and 10). Then it draws them on a picturebox with a buttonclick action and then the user could click on any dot and a line between them is drawn.
So far it looks like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().Clear(this.BackColor);
        Random r = new Random();
        int db = new int();
        Graphics rl = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        db = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        if (db > 0 && db < 11)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < db; i++)
            {
                rl.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), r.Next(4, pictureBox1.Width - 4), r.Next(4, pictureBox1.Height - 4), 5, 5);


            }
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong number!");
        }
    }
```

This only draws the point on the form and i want to make them linkable. My idea is that i put it on a bitmap then i check the x,y coordinates and if the color is black (which means there is a point) I store in dot1 and dot2 and then simply make a drawline command like this:

```
private bool first = false;
    private void Picturebox_Mouse(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
    {

        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        Color color = bm.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
        if (color == Color.Black & first==false)
        {
            dot1.X = e.X;
            dot1.Y = e.Y;
            first = true;
        }
        if (color == Color.Black & first == true)
        {
            dot2.X = e.X;
            dot2.Y = e.X;
            first = false;
        }
        rl.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), dot1, dot2);
    }
```

My question is that is my approach fine or i should do a different way? Also if this can work how do i put the content of the picturebox into a bitmap? I tried to drawing the point into the bitmap diractly then setting the pictureboxs image to the bitmap:

```
pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(r.Next(0, pictureBox1.Width - 4), r.Next(0, pictureBox1.Height - 4), 5, 5));
        pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = bm;
```

and also i tried to reverse it so putting the content to the bitmap:

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
```

but it doesn't seem to work. So can i get some ideas how to do it?
Any Kind of Idea is Appriciated!Thanks you.

Comment: The problem with your approach is your users are going to have to be extremely accurate with their clicking to hit a pixel, you'd be better of keeping a list of points and then checking if the users click is anywhere near any of them (set a tolerance).

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar, but as I was doing it on a web page I used an ImageButton instead of a PictureBox, so my code doesn't do exactly what you need, unfortunately.  However, to use a bitmap with your image, you can do something like this:

```
Bitmap flag = new Bitmap(200, 100);
using(Graphics flagGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(flag))
{
// draw something on flagGraphics
pictureBox1.Image = flag;
}
```

(I actually based this on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404307(v=vs.110).aspx)

Note, you will need to change your test for black to something like  `if(color.ToArgb() == Color.Black.ToArgb())` or it won't work.  Also you are setting a Y to an X value when I think it should be a Y!